# Can't connect mobile device to local MySQL database, but works using emulator

Tags: php, android, mysql, http, server

I can't connect my mobile device to my local MySQL database. I'm using Wamp server 64 bits. However it perfectly works on the emulator device.
I just followed this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4e8be8xseqE.

When I run the app on the emulator, the adress 10.0.2.2 works.
When I run the app on my own device, I change the adress to 127.0.0.1 or my IPv4.
I even tried to connect my mobile to my computer wifi's hotspot, and use the specific IPv4 but that didn't work.

Also I installed Android Terminal Emulator and pinged my compter's IP but that didn't work... That's really strange because my mobile is well connected to the same wifi network than my computer.

Android code to connect to the local MySQL database :

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://192.168.1.34/login.php";
            if(type.equals("login")) {
            try {
                String username = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                        URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                        URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "ISO-8859-1"));

                String result = "";
                String line;

                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }

                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return result;

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

PHP scripts :
connect.php

```
<?php

$db_name = "employee101";
$mysql_username = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$server_name = "localhost";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $db_name);

?>
```

login.php

```
<?php

require "conn.php";

$user_name = $_POST["username"];
$user_name = $_POST["password"];
$user_pass = "123";
$mysql_qry = "select * from employee_data where username like '$user_name' and password like '$user_pass';";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $mysql_qry);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    echo "login success";
}
else
{
    echo "login not success";
}

?>
```

So, on the emulator that displays a Toast with the message "login success".
On my own device, there is no message. I don't know what's wrong.

Do you have any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: put your testing device and system in one network

Comment: I know my code is vulnerable but atm it is not important. I'll use prepared statements when the connection will work

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I already said I don't care about security atm. This is a test project and the fundamental thing doesn't work (that is mysql local database connection)

Answer (score 0):

you need to connect both your system and device in which you testing in one wifi(network)
your emulator is in your system so it is working.

Comment: My device is already connected to the same wifi than my computer

Answer (score 0):

can you try using json response

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $data['status'] = 200;
    $data['message'] = "login success";
    echo json_encode($data);
}
else
{
    $data['status'] = 200;
    $data['message'] = "login not success";
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: The problem is not in your code, your device and system not in same network ether you connect your system with WIFI and mobile in same network OR create your mobile Hotspot  with your system check the IP it will work fine.

Comment: The result is : {"status":200,"message":"login success"} on the emulator.

Comment: I have already tried to connect my mobile to the same network or on the system wifi's hotspot. I used the wifi adapter IPv4 (which is by default 192.168.137.1). It doesn't work

Comment: check login url which is use are using inside your code.

Comment: I use the url 192.168.1.34 when my phone and my computer are connected to the same wifi network.
Currently, I use 192.168.137.1 because my phone is connected to the windows wifi hotspot.

Comment: Well. I fixed the problem I coudln't ping my PC from my phone : that was a firewall restriction. I used that command to solve it : 

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow

Answer (score 0):

So, I fixed the problem I couldn't ping my PC from my phone. That was a firewall restriction. I simply added an exception by using this command :

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow
```

However, I keep not connecting my phone to my MySQL local database. My phone is connected to my PC's wifi hotspot. His IP is, at the moment, 192.168.137.204.

In my code, I'm using this url : "http://192.168.137.1/login.php" because 192.168.137.1 is my PC's IP (in the local network). But it's still not working...